# Django Redirect to different URL base on forms choice

Tags: python, django

Hello I stack with redirect to different pages base on Form Choice in Django. I have 4 different choices to pick, but everyone has different next page. I do something like this :

forms.py

```
class DodajForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Atrakcje
    exclude = ['user']
    fields = ['tytul', 'opis', 'kategoriaa', 'adres',
     'wojewodztwo', 'miasto', 'telefon', 'zdjecie', 'wideo',
     'email', 'strona', 'facebook', 'kodpocztowy', 'zaswiadczenia', 'pakiet', 'cena', 'dla']
    widgets = {
        'kategoriaa': forms.Select(
             attrs={
                'class': 'form-control'
            }
        ),
         'pakiet': forms.Select(
             attrs={
                'class': 'form-control'
            }
        ),
        'tytul': forms.TextInput(
             attrs={
                'class': 'form-label'
            }
        ),
        'opis': forms.Textarea(
             attrs={
                'class': 'form-control'
            }
        ),
          'zdjecie': forms.FileInput(
             attrs={
                'class': 'dropzone dz-clickable',

            }
        ),

       'zaswiadczenia': forms.FileInput(
             attrs={
                'class': 'dropzone dz-clickable',

            }
        ),

    }
```

views.py

```
def formularz(request):
form = DodajForm(request.POST)   
if form.is_valid():
    ogloszenie = form.save(commit=False)
    ogloszenie.user = request.user 
    ogloszenie.save()
    if form.pakiet == "free":

        return redirect('atrakcje:after') 
    elif form.pakiet == "pakiet1":
        return redirect('atrakcje:after1') 
    elif form.pakiet == "pakiet2":
        return redirect('atrakcje:after2') 
    else:
        return redirect('atrakcje:after3') 
else:
    ogloszenie = DodajForm()
context = {
            'form': form,}
return render(request, 'formularz.html', context)
```

and I have error on every choice like this :

"AttributeError at /atrakcje/formularz/
'DodajForm' object has no attribute 'pakiet'

There is a error on this line :
if form.pakiet == "free":

Any recommendations how to resolve this please?

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `form.cleaned_data['pakiet']`

Comment: Thanks a lot is working well ! You are my HERO ! :D

Answer (score 1):

you need to first extract data for 'pakiet' field from form like this

```
data = form.cleaned_data['pakiet']
if data  == "free":
    return redirect('atrakcje:after') 
elif data  == "pakiet1":
    return redirect('atrakcje:after1') 
elif data  == "pakiet2":
    return redirect('atrakcje:after2') 
else:
    return redirect('atrakcje:after3')
```